# Fix $k.$ Is $n^{k} > (n-2)^{k} + (n-1)^{k}$ true for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: real-analysis, integers

Does the proof change for different $k$? Can there be a single, clean way of expressing this for any positive $k$ and $n$?

Comment: This is most definitely false. Consider the case $n=4, k=1$

Comment: This statement does not hold for $n=1$, since $1^k\not> (-1)^k$ necessarily for every $k\in \Bbb N$.

Comment: Please explain what you have tried. Otherwise it just looks like you're asking us to do your homework for you, and we don't do that here at MSE.

Comment: @Cathedral how about for k >= 2?

Comment: When $~k = 2,~$ do you need help exploring what happens when $~n=4~$ or $~n=5~$ or $~n=6~$ ?

Comment: @cuffty for any $k \ge 1$ , there is some $n$ above which your mentioned inequality does not hold. If you don't see why, consider what happens when $n \to \infty$

Comment: @Cathedral thanks!

Comment: Probably need to think about what $n$ and $k$ are appropriate. $7^2\not > 5^2 + 6^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counterexamples in comments prove the relationship is not universally true.

If you expand expressions, sum, and look at the first few terms, you get $$n^k>2n^k-3kn^{k-1} +\text{terms}$$
You might imagine that this could run into trouble in the vicinity of $3k\approx n$, which reduces the above relationship to (something close to) $$n^k>n^k +\text{terms}$$
the truth of which would depend on the the cummulative sign of the further terms.

Comment: Your ending statement is false. $n>>3k$ can be taken to be $n\to \infty $. We can divide both sides of our inequality by $n^k$ to get $1>(\frac{n-1}{n})^k+(\frac{n-2}{n})^k$. As $n \to \infty $, both terms on our rhs $\to 1$. This gives us $1>2$, and as such is clearly wrong.

Comment: @Cathrdral You're right; statement deleted.

Answer (score 0):

No. For example, alluding to Cathedral's comment:

$$(n-2)^k + (n-1)^k > 2(n-2)^k  > n^k $$

$$\Leftarrow 2> \left( \frac{n}{n-2} \right)^k \Leftarrow \ldots \Leftarrow n> \frac{2}{2^{\frac{1}{k}}-1} + 2$$